# Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Express Edition SP4 wasn't installed

Tags: windows-xp, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2005

I lost track of my account when my [question](https://superuser.com/questions/303154/microsoft-sql-server-2005-express-edition-updates) was moved to superuser.

I wasn't able to install *`Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Express Edition SP4`* through automatic update so I downloaded the update from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=184) and tried manual install, which was also failed with some error:

> The components that you are trying to
>   install are already installed

I checked the product version of sql server 2005 which returned `9.00.5000.00`  through command `Select @@version`.

Now the question is, if the automatic update wasn't able to apply the SP4 patch then how come the version is updated to `9.00.5000.00` ?

There is no way to rollback or reinstall the patch as it takes the entire SQL Server which came with Visual Studio 2005 to be re-installed.

Is there any other way I can verify that SP4 patch was properly applied?

**Edit**: I used MBSA Tool to analyze the required updates which confirms that the Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Express Edition SP4 is missing.

Comment: I found this link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2463332 helpful to troubleshoot the similar issues as I mentioned. Gonna give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what "it won't install" means, and I've also never heard of the updates coming out of order like that (the most recent usually supersedes older ones).

But you can install SP4 manually instead of relying on Windows Update:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=184

Answer (score 0):

They would need to be installed in order (sp2, sp3, sp4)

You got them as your PC must have SQLExpress installed.

Comment: SQL Server service packs are cumulative. If you are going to install SP4, there is no reason to install SP2 or SP3 at all.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that since it is reporting the version number correctly (as in the document below), it is installed correctly unless you are getting some error. I cannot speculate as to how it got installed, but you seem to be on SP4.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185